# How to select files from google drive in android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, filepicker

Is there any way to start file picker for google drive in android app - to do something similar to this http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/08/allowing-user-to-select-google-drive.html. I need to allow user to select files from google drive, so I can use their bytes in my application. Thanks.

Comment: did you find any related tutorials for this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a file picker in the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro). The best place to see it's use is [this demo](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos), specifically the [Intents](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos#intents) section.

There are 2 methods in the demo you are interested in:

1. the 'Pick a file with opener activity' ,
2. and the 'Pick a folder with opener activity'

but they are essentially the same, differing only in the MIME TYPE filter specified here:

```
IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
 .setMimeType(new String[] { DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE })  // <--- FOLDER
 //.setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" }) // <- TEXT FILES
 .build(getGoogleApiClient());
```

Good Luck

Comment: go [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos), find the 'Intents' section, click away...

Comment: For this to work you must call this intent after the GoogleApiClient successfully connected (probably in the overridden onConnected(Bundle hints) method)

Comment: @seanpj is possible to pick a folder (not in app created) by default without Intent and using GDAA ?

Comment: The Drive Android API is deprecated as of December 6, 2018 and will be turned down on December 6, 2019. https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

Answer (score 2):

There is an api for this. I think this google's documentation should help https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries. I'm not sure on how you want to go about it.

Comment: Note that as of December 2018, the API in this link is now in the process of being deprecated by Google.